# Why my billing address is repeating in the order success page?

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, onepage-checkout

After successful placed order, the success page contains a repetitive billing address like ..

```
james dohg
riverside lane
56 arches park
56 arches park
56 arches park
56 arches park
sulket, ph5 3np
united Kingdom
T: 02045698630 
F: 02055555630
```

It doesn't appear all the time but sometimes it is coming like this.
I can't understand what is the problem.
Is it at the time of customer address entry during the checkout process ?

Comment: Why did I get -1 ?

Comment: Probably because you have provided 0 information. Does this happen with the default theme?

Comment: @SR_Magento, No. It is not happening with default theme. and it happens occasionally, not always. I don't know what else to provide here ?

Comment: So its your theme - check your files the problem is there.

Comment: You mean to say success.phtml file ? or any autocomplete function is there while saving ?

Comment: Remove the success.phtml from your theme and it will be fine.

Comment: I got it, what are you trying to tell me..anyway thanks..@SR_Magento

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are describing is custom theme related. Since it works with the default theme, the file responsible would be `success.phtml` remove this file and your issue will be resolved.

Comment: How can I check ? As I have told that it happens occasionally .

Comment: If you have a `success.phtml` in your theme, remove it and try some test orders it wont happen again.

Comment: I have already done it. and it works fine. But I want to know how can I be sure that it won't happen again. Because you see, it was not happening before . Last 2 -3 days some orders (not all) have been like this.. So I guess may be it  is the customer's multiple input that causes like this..

Comment: If it was in the custom success.phtml file then it should happen for all the success orders. but it is not.